# Are files in src/test/resources on classpath while application (src/main) is running?

Tags: java, spring-boot

newbie here!
I found a lot of similar questions on SO, but none of them gave me a strait answer.

I wrote tests for all layers including the persistence layer in my spring-boot application. For testing the persistence layer I used H2 database. I used @DataJpaTest annotation and placed schema.sql and data.sql scripts to src/test/resources/db folder to create a schema and populate it with data from data.sql. And it works fine, all tests passing using that data.

Now what I am trying to do is to set up an integration test with @SpringBootTest to test whole application - top to bottom, from web layer to data layer. I made an application-test.properties with H2 config and annotated my test class with @ActiveProfiles("test") and it works fine. When I run this test class, application context fires up, H2 is up too, but of course, there is no data there. I would like to populate my in-memory database with the same date from data.sql from src/test/resources/db.

I modified application-test.properties in this way: 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:db/schema.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:db/data.sql' 
and I got org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource /db/schema.sql" exception.

I have done a lot of googling and I found more resources saying src/main/resources and src/test/resources are both on the classpath. If so, why am I getting this exception?

Also, when I put those two scripts to src/main/resources/db it works fine. Also, it works fine when I run my persistence layer test no matter if those scripts are in src/main/resources/db or src/test/resources/db. So, it looks like a test environment using both src/main/resources and src/test/resources locations as classpath, but the environment uses only src/main/resources as classpath!? Could it be true?

One possible solution I tried and its works is not to run those scripts (removing INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:db/schema.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:db/data.sql' from .properties file) and before test programmatically create some object and persist them to database and then write test, but I think it is much easier and leaner to populate data from script than write this code in every test class.

Another possible solution is to copy those scripts from src/test/resources/db to src/main/resources/db, but it means I would have duplicated data and I hate that. Also, it means harder to maintaince.

The next possible solution is to put those scripts to src/main/resources/db because, as I said, data persistence test works fine no matter if those scripts are in src/main/resources/db or src/test/resources/db. But, those scripts are related to tests so I think they belong there not in the main part of the application.

And also, if I provide an absolute path to those scripts, it works fine, but it means my team members would have to modify it to fit their machines. Not really optimal solution.

So, my questions are:
1. Is it true that the test environment using both src/main/resources and src/test/resources locations as classpath, but the main environment uses only src/main/resources as classpath?
2. How can I resolve this challenge?

Comment: You can access the src/main/ resources from src/test/ resources, but not vise versa.
It's good practice to put your test code related classes to the src/test/java instead of using 'test' profile.

Comment: @androberz so that is rule!? Great to know! Every answer I found said both locations are on classpath, nothing more. Regarding my test, all related classes are already in src/test/java. I used @ActivePRofiles("test") annotation in order to run H2 database instead of mysql one. In that way, I tried to perform testing on data from H2 database. It works. But it looks like main application context is up, so I can't access to a script located in src/test/resource folder. Am I doing something wrong? Should I modify some configs or something? It is really hard to find a decent articles on this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it true that the test environment using both `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` locations as classpath, but the main environment uses only `src/main/resources` as classpath?

Yes. It is true. In both Maven and Gradle `test` classpath is inherited from `main` and not vice versa. It means that classes and resources from `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` are available during test execution, but `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources` are not reachable by the main codebase. Also note that test classes and resources are not transitive, i.e. they are not available in a depended projects.

> How can I resolve this challenge?

Well, there are many solutions:

1. Place the resources in `src/main` (obviously)
2. Extract the resources you need in both places into a separate module and depend on it.
3. Use [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin) to copy the files from other locations.

Comment: Thank you very much, @madhead ! As I already explained, it seems somehow strange to put them to src/main because they are related only to test. And another solution you mentioned I have no idea how to implement, but I am going to google it.

Comment: @meadhead One more thing: does it make sense to organize the tests in the way I described earlier, using an in-memory database, populate it with some data, and then perform tests? I'm talking about integration test throught whole application.

Comment: It makes a perfect sense. Many projects do that. Though it is not a pure unit test, why not?

Comment: If the resource is needed only in tests, then put it in test resource directory and do not use in the main codebase.

Comment: Thank for your answers, it is very helpful. I like the idea of putting it only in the test resource directory, but how can I then fire up my test with @SpringBootTest - it fires up the main application context? Is there a better solution? I am just thinking, even if I configure Maven to copy files, there will be the same files in src/main/resource directory and will serve only to testing???

Comment: Files in `src/test/*` take precedence over `src/main` in tests. For tests you can also use `application-test.properties` that will override the main one.

Comment: Somebody give this man a hug! Thank you, man, you helped me a lot! I spent hours trying o solve this. Maybe I'm not looking at the right places,  but it is very hard to find his kind of tips.